# how to send data from iOS prototype cell to watch with swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, watchkit, watchconnectivity

How can I code with Watch Connectivity messages for my watch to get values returned from my iOS phone table view prototype cells?
The prototype cells include a title name, which is stored in realm as self.specimen.name, and node ID, self.specimen.nid, My watch needs to display the users' selected prototype cell title (self.specimen.name) as a text label on my watch and use the NID (self.specimen.nid) in an API data post call.

How do I set up the watch connectivity, so that my watch knows the results from the prototype cells and I can use 'self.specimen.name' for my label and 'self.specimen.nid' in my api function (my question marks in the code)

I have read about how to do the wcsession setup (eg the code below carrying the message) but am unsure what are the message data values I should include?
in this code below, what would be the request values i'm sending/ receiving?

```
if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable == true {

    let requestValues = ["?" : "?"]
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()

    session.sendMessage(requestValues, replyHandler: { reply in
        self.statusLabel.setText(reply["status"] as? String)
        }, errorHandler: { error in
            print("error: \(error)")
    })
```

I am a beginner and finding the data communication confusing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please work though some tutorials and actually try things out, to clear up your confusion. In this question, you haven't tried anything, and are asking us to fill in the blanks and give you the specific code you need. SO isn't a code-writing service. A better question would be "Here is the code I tried.  It doesn't do what I expect it to."

Comment: It really sounds like you want the watch to show the phone's current context. Wouldn't `updateApplicationContext` be a better path for passing details about the current selection *in the background*? This might be a better approach than trying to interactively send current details, and having the watch do the heavy lifting with some API request. (What if the user selects another row on the phone? How do you handle cancelling outstanding requests made on the watch? What if the watch app isn't in the foreground?) In short, keep things simple on the watch side, and do the work on the phone.